# Error on converting flutter project to APK, error files coming from AppData

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

So I tried every possible way and ask from different people, and I also tried updating dependencies on my project but to only possible latest version since there's a version constraint. Here's the full error

`https://pastebin.com/r6ZEPURC`

```
Script 'C:\Users\Rodrigo\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1151

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\Rodrigo\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

How can I fix this issue? thanks.

I tried updating my dependencies and changing some parts of my code, but it still doesn't work. I was trying to build it into an APK for a few days now, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Add complete log

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue with the modal_bottom_sheet package conflicting with material bottom sheet. You need to follow the recommendations there to get your app to build. See: https://github.com/jamesblasco/modal_bottom_sheet/issues/328

As a general rule, it is always a good idea to check the package's GitHub repo issues section when you see errors like this.